# If functions not working in AppleScript when used with lists

Tags: applescript

I am trying to form a script to open up a different classroom depending on what subject I have but am not finding success.

This is the script I've used.

```
set theList to {"Maths", "Further Maths", "Physics", "Chemistry"}
set lesson to choose from list theList with prompt "What lesson do you have?"
if lesson is equal to "Further Maths" then
do shell script "open https://classroom.google.com/u/0/c/A"
end if
```

And so on with the other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`choose from list` returns always a list (or `false` if the user presses the Cancel button) even if `with multiple selections allowed` is not specified.

In *single choice mode* you have to get the first item of the list

```
set theList to {"Maths", "Further Maths", "Physics", "Chemistry"}
set lesson to choose from list theList with prompt "What lesson do you have?"
if lesson is false then return
if (item 1 of lesson) is equal to "Further Maths" then
    do shell script "open https://classroom.google.com/u/0/c/A"
end if
```